How to open a modal presentation on expo but open it to half the screen?
I'm trying to change my code actually to use the new navigation of expo and I was using the gorhom bottomsheet for a lot of things but the expo navigation can use inside de navigation the "presentation": "modal" to do almost the same job.
And actually here my page gorhom modal don't take all the screen sometimes juste the half, but with the expo navigation it takes the full screen.
      <Stack.Screen
        name="modalTranslate"
        options={{
          presentation: 'modal',
        }}
      />

